# Linux: Append variable to end of line using line number as variable

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

I am new to shell scripting. I am using ksh.

I have this particular line in my script which I use to append text in a variable `q` to the end of a particular line given by the variable `a`
 containing the line number .

```
sed -i ''$a's@$@'"$q"'@' test.txt
```

Now the variable `q` can contain a large amount of text, with all sorts of special characters, such as !@#$%^&*()_+:"<>.,/;'[]= etc etc, no exceptions. 
 For now, I use a couple of sed commands in my script to remove any ' and " in this text (`sed "s/'/ /g" | sed 's/"/ /g'`), but still when I execute the above command I get the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 168: unterminated `s' command
```

Any sed, awk, perl, suggestions are very much appreciated

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like an XY Problem. Can you backtrack a bit, and give some examples of what you're trying to do (input and outputs)?

Comment: So `$a` is here a line number in `test.txt`?

Comment: `perl -i -pe 's/$/ $./' file`

Comment: You could try: `perl -pi -E 'BEGIN {$q = shift; $a = shift} s/$/$q/ if $. == $a' "$q" "$a" test.txt`

Comment: @Hakon, you are right $a contains the line number in test.txt

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, great great suggestion!, it worked brilliantly, perl is king no doubt.
Would you be so kind to post this as an answer with explanation for me to also learn :)

Comment: @DineshKumar Added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is to quote (escape) the substitution separator characters `@` in the sed command:

```
sed -i ''$a's@$@'"$q"'@' test.txt
```

For example, if `q` contains `@` it will not work. The `@` will terminate the replacement pattern prematurely. Example: `q='a@b'`, `a=2`, and the command expands to

```
sed -i 2s@$@a@b@ test.txt
```

which will not append `a@b` to the end of line 2, but rather `a@`.

This can be solved by escaping the `@` characters in `q`:

```
sed -i 2s@$@a\@b@ test.txt
```

However, this escaping could be cumbersome to do in shell.
Another approach is to use another level of indirection. Here is an example of using a Perl one-liner. First `q` is passed to the script in quoted form. Then, within the script the variable assigned to a new internal variable `$q`. Using this approach there is no need to escape the substitution separator characters:

```
perl -pi -E 'BEGIN {$q = shift; $a = shift} s/$/$q/ if $. == $a' "$q" "$a" test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not bother trying to sanitize the string.  Just put it in a file, and use sed's `r` command to read it in:

```
echo "$q" > tmpfile
sed -i -e ${a}rtmpfile test.txt
```

Ah, but that creates an extra newline that you don't want.  You can remove it with:

```
sed -e ${a}rtmpfile test.txt | awk 'NR=='$a'{printf $0; next}1' > output
```

Comment: Hi William, thanks for the suggestion, but I really want to handle this operation in memory. This line of code is inside a For loop that will be executed more than 10,000 times

Comment: @DineshKumar Just IMHO - calling `sed` 10k times (and even more, as you said in the question) doesn't sound for me as an _efficient_ solution. but - ok - ymmv...

Comment: Write the tempfile outside of the loop.  Chances are very good that it will never hit disk, as the OS will keep it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the patch utility if present in your system.

```
patch test.txt <<-EOF
${a}c
$(sed "${a}q;d" test.txt)$q
.
EOF
```

`${a}c` will be replaced with the line number followed by `c` which means the operation is a change in line `${a}`.

The second line is the replacement of the change. This is the concatenated value of the original text and the added text.

The sole `.` means execute the commands.